# Why does indexing anonymous tuple in f-string give an error?

Tags: python, tuples, f-string

I am trying to understand why this is happening:

```
>>> selection = False
>>> a = ("NO", "YES")
>>> print(f"{a[int(selection)]}")
NO
>>> print(f"{("NO", "YES")[int(selection)]}")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(f"{("NO", "YES")[int(selection)]}")
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

All I think I know about Python makes me think that this should work just fine, but since it obviously is not, there is a learning opportunity here.

Can someone explain why is indexing anonymous tuple not recognized as valid syntax in Python (3.7.3), please?

**NOTE:** I am not looking for alternate ways to do this, but to learn and understand this particular error, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotation marks are the problem. They terminate the f-string and need to be <strike>escaped or</strike> replaced by `'`.

Comment: [Escaping quotes doesn't work](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences) in the expression portion of f-strings. Using single- instead of double-quotes is a more likely solution.

Comment: Oh for ..... sake! *major facepalm*. Yes, indeed. You are absolutely right!